# Pass matrix as argument

Tags: c, matrix, c89

I want to pass two matrices as argument. These matrices have different size and i don't understand how i have to do this work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void f(int m[3][], int n);

int main()
{
  int A[3][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5, 6},{7,8,9}};
  int B[3][2]={{1,2},{3, 4}, {5, 6}};

  f(A, 3);
  f(B, 2);

  return 0;
}

 void f(int m[3][], int n)
 {
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
      for(j=0;j<n;j++)
       printf("%5d", m[i][j]);
    }
    return;
 }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What is not working? Are you getting a compile-time error?

Comment: Are you using [C89](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C89_(C_version)#C89), [C99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99), or some compiler-specific dialect of C?  There are differences in the ways that you can pass matrix arguments to functions, depending on which language version your compiler is configured to accept.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen yes main.c|5|error: array type has incomplete element type
/main.c|12|error: type of formal parameter 1 is incomplete

Comment: Check the [C FAQ 6.18 and 6.19](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only safe way that I know of to do this is to include the matrix dimensions in the parameters, or make some kind of matrix struct

Option A) dimensions as parameters

```
void f(int **m, int w, int h )
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<w;i++)
    {
      for(j=0;j<h;j++)
         printf("%5d", m[i][j]);
    }
    return;
}
```

Option B) Use a struct

```
typedef struct Matrix
{
    int w, h;
    int** m;
} Matrix;

void f ( Matrix *m )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < m->w; ++i )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < m->h; ++j )
        {
            printf(%5d", m->m[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is ok for C89, I'd just like to note that for C99 much easier solutions exist.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the C99 standard.  Out of curiosity, what is added in C99 that would make for easier solutions?

Comment: You can have interfaces like `void f(size_t n, int m[3][n])` with real 2D matrices with dynamic bounds as a parameter. You may have a look at https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2011/01/13/vla-as-function-arguments/