# why does this code throw a seg fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
void f(int **m, int w, int h )  
{       
int i,j;

    for(i=0;i < w ; i++)  
    {    
      for(j=0;j<h;j++)
      {
         printf("%5d", m[i][j]); //  *( *(m + i) + j ) ??
      }

    printf("\n");
    }
    return;
}


int main()
{

int a[3][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5, 6},{7,8,9}};


f(a,3,3);

}
```

this code is trying to print a 2d matrix
but i get a segmentation fault.

Comment: what is your matrix creation code ?

Comment: you're probably walking off the end of your array. we need to see the declaration/allocation of m and values for w, h

Comment: This is fastest downvote spiral i have seen :)

Comment: @NickWiggill codereview is for working code, segfaulting code belongs here.

Comment: @nhahtdh: `w` and `h` are the dimensions. @parapura: word!

Comment: You have to show the calling code, and how the matrix is created. Without that, it's impossible to diagnose.

Comment: by the way i found this code on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625547/pass-matrix-as-argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your matrix is not of type `int **`, its type is `int[3][]`.

`int **` means a pointer to an array of pointers. You don't have an array of pointers, you have an array of 3-integer-arrays. It's not the same thing.

If you want you can change your code to take that into account.

```
int *addr = (int *)m;  // This is the address of m[0][0]
```

To access m[i][j] use:

```
int elem = addr[i*h+j];
```

Comment: To illustrate (the parameter): http://ideone.com/sbEb5

Comment: that's what i thought... these five up votes made me ask this question  
stackoverflow.com/questions/10625547/pass-matrix-as-argument

Answer (score 1):

A pointer to a pointer to an `int` is not the same as a `3x3` array.

You should either declare your function differently, or prepare your array differently:

Change `f` to this:

```
void f(int m[][3], int w, int h )
```

Or prepare the array like this:

```
int r0[] = {1,2,3};
int r1[] = {4,5,6};
int r2[] = {7,8,9};
int *a[] = {r0,r1,r2};
f(a,3,3);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int a[3][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5, 6},{7,8,9}};
```

passing that to `f` doesn't work, `a`'s type is incompatible with the type `f` expects. When passed to a function, `a` is converted to a pointer of type `int (*)[3]`, pointer to array of three `int`.

`f` expects a pointer to pointer to `int`. Your compiler should have told you about the incompatible types.

What happens is undefined behaviour, probably when dereferencing `m` in `f`, the first `sizeof(int*)` bytes of the array contents are interpreted as a pointer and followed, leading to accessing unallocated memory.